# Error.code no longer valid syntax in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Recently converted my app from the previous version to swift 3. Predictably, this caused a lot of errors in my code. I do not know how to fix the following one:
(In the `Appdelegate.swift`):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
        }
    }
```

The error given is that the value of type error has no member "code". How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting error to NSError

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    if (error as NSError).code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift2+, the function named

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
```

in swift3+, the function named

```
optional func application(_ application: NSApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
```

the type of `error` change from `NSError` to `Error`.

the `code` is the property of `NSError`